# SSDT <<project could not be deployed>> <<a connection cannot be made. ensure the server is running>>

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, sql-data-tools

I have been trying to deploy a solution from SQL Server Data Tools to my sql server. However, whenever I try to, i get the following error (I'm sorry its in french, the second screenshot in an equivalent of it I found online):

[image: Error in french]

[image: Error in english]

I set up my server name in the project properties

[image: Deployment properties]
as it is in the my server properties

[image: Server properties]

I'm doing this for an academic project (which is why I'm using sql 2014), but I'm kind of stuck here and can't get any further, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: That error says you're deployed to the `localhost` not the server `HAMZA`.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: What type of project are you trying to deploy here? That's an express instance, which means that it does not support SSAS and SSIS, and if you're deploying an SSRS report, then I would suggest that the error is correct, and SSRS isn't running (that last screen shot is of the Data Engine, which is unrelated to the problem)

Comment: I'm trying to deploy a cube into my sql server, to be honest I'm new to sql and I'm just following a guide in the book our teacher gave us (Business Intelligence with SQL server 2014)

Comment: *"I'm trying to deploy a cube into my sql server,"* You're using Express, you can't. ONly Standard, Enterprise and Developer support SSAS.

Comment: I just upgraded to Enterprise edition, the same problem occurs.

Comment: I tried Developer edition too, just in case, it still doesn't work

Comment: And is the SSAS service running? I suspect not.

Comment: No, when I check my services I dont see Analysis Services

Comment: You didn't install it then. You need to install and run SSAS to be able to deploy to it.

Comment: I have been trying to install the analysis services through "Add features" in sql setup , but I cant find analysis services in the features tree even though it says that this instance is Enterprise in the wizard screen before. Any idea why?

Comment: @H.Ka Mircosoft has a lot of documentation, some even titled [Install SQL Server Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/install-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions)

Comment: @H.Ka before you try to deploy your cubes via SSDT, try to connect to the SSAS instance first by using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). You'll need to select proper "Server Type" when connecting to instance.